# Problem with DevExpress and just my machine

Tags: c#, asp.net

**I can navigate to the class in intellisense in the CS. I know it's there. Just can't figure out why I'm getting this error. The project works fine on other peoples computers.**

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.StylesBase' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'DevExpress.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a'.

Source Error:

Line 224: 
Line 225: [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 226: private void @__BuildControl__control2(DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GridViewStyles @__ctrl) {
Line 227: 
Line 228: #line 33 "E:\...\page.aspx"


Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\94947553\afb27c33\App_Web_pagemanager.aspx.8f36609.6x9twr-m.0.cs    Line: 226
```

Comment: What happens when you do what the error message is telling you to do?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this assembly reference in your project?  And if you do is it the right version? or do you have Specific Version = True (if you don't have the exact version).

Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.StylesBase' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'DevExpress.Web.v11.1, Version=11.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a'.

If you have have the reference and Specific Version = False it should work.

Comment: I agree.  this is a local configuration problem.  Most likely the OP doesn't have the same version of DevExpress installed.

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you might be in a situation I was in earlier this year, so I will tell you what worked for me:

Right click on your project in Solution Explorer and click on the Application tab.  Check that your target framework is ".NET Framework 4" (or 3.5 etc.).

If it is targeting ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" and the DevExpress assembily makes use of features not available to the cliet profile, then you find that your reference is ignored.

[image]

Comment: Since the target framework is part of the project file, wouldn't everyone else who use the project have the same problem?

Comment: Well, yes, assuming it really is the same on his computer as other peoples.  It was just one idea to check.